# Error 1026 Received in ActionScript 3 even with the constructor being an instance method

Tags: actionscript-3

I have got a problem with my actionscript class. This is my code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

It produces the following 2 errors.

- /.../Main.as, Line 1 5000: The class 'Main' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.
- 1026: Constructor functions must be instance methods.

I don't know what is causing the errors as the do not when i press Check Syntax.
I am using OSX 10.6.6 and Adobe CS 5 Trial Edition if those specs help.

Comment: Try making your constructor (function Main) public. It can't be instantiated if it's private.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem, but is there a reason the constructor is `private`?

Comment: what happens if you make your constructor public? Oh wow, way late.

Comment: i was just playing around, i tested it with constructor being public and the same problems, thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: What's the linkage like in your flash project like?

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to reproduce these errors. A quick perusal through Google tells me you most likely have a naming conflict with `Main`.

Comment: You are Absolutely Brilliant, Thanks. You were right. Thanks

Comment: Be sure to mark my answer as the correct one, then. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I indicated through the comments, a 1026 error is commonly a naming conflict with the class. "Main" tends to be a very common name.