# Flash AS3: 1026 Error: Constructor functions must be instance methods

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, constructor, compiler-errors

When I run my code it gives me a compiler error 1026 that says "Constructor functions must be instance methods". It sends me to the movieclip that contains this code, although even if I comment it out, it sends me to the same spot

```
var resources:Array = new Array(1);
var enemies:Array = new Array();
resources[0] = new Resource();
```

I saw other people with the same error, but their problems were all spelling mistakes on the name of the exported object.

Any ideas?

Comment: debug your movie (ctrl+shift+enter) instead of running it (ctrl+enter), you will have more information about the problem i think. After that make sure you don't have a symbol named Resource on your timeline and that you have a livrary symbol exported for actionscript with the name Resource

Comment: Shouldn't the var resources:Array = new Array(1); instead of 0?

Comment: If you comment the code and still have the error, the error is not there ;)

Comment: Is Resource defined as a static class?

Comment: ctl+shift+enter didn't make a difference
I have a lot of nested timelines, but the find and replace search for the symbol Resource came up with no results
And the library symbol has export for actionscript with the name Resource

Comment: sorry about the Array(0). I tried it both ways
and @Binou, I kinda thought that, but I have no idea where it is then

Comment: how do I find whether it is a static class @bcollins?

Comment: static class doesn't exists in as3.

Comment: I think your problem is not on these 3 lines. May be try to clean your publish cache after commenting these lines to see if the error is still here...

Comment: By any chance, have you named your class "Main"?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201804/error-1026-received-in-actionscript-3-even-with-the-constructor-being-an-instanc

Comment: And this is why we don't do time-lime programming.

Comment: sorry, but how do I access the publish cache?

Comment: I don't have any classes named Main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happened was that the symbol hadn't been given time to load yet, so resources hadn't been initiated by the time I tried to make changes. I changed the array initiation so that it happens in the code that I use to access it, and it doesn't give the error anymore.